# java.lang.IllegalStateException: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So i'm building a spring 3.2.3.RELEASE / hibernate 4.0.1.FINAL application and i got the following exception

> [2017-03-22 09:29:47,860] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [localhost-startStop-1] Ignoring bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginService' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Programmes/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/webapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-transactional-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Programmes/apache-tomcat-7.0.33/webapps/perWeb/WEB-INF/lib/perService-2.0.jar!/applicationContext-simple-service.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'ma.dao.impl.GenericDAO' to required type 'ma.dao.IGenericDAO' for property 'dao'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [ma.dao.impl.GenericDAO] to required type [ma.dao.IGenericDAO] for property 'dao': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Here is my beans: loginservice

```
<bean id="loginService"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="transactionManagerPER" />
        </property>
        <property name="target">
            <ref bean="loginServiceImpl" />
        </property>
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="loadUserByUsername">
                    PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,-Exception
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

loginServiceImpl

```
<bean id="loginServiceImpl"
          class="ma.service.login.LoginService">
        <property name="dao">
            <ref bean="userDAO" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

UserDAO

```
<bean id="userDAO"
        class="ma.dao.impl.GenericDAO">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>
                ma.dao.mappings.Utilisateur
            </value>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactoryPER" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Utilisateur.Java

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(
        {
            @NamedQuery(name="findUtilisateurByName", 
                    query = "select user from Utilisateur user where user.login=:userName"
                    ) 
        }
)
public class Utilisateur implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7214071893495381842L;
    private Integer id;
    private Profil  profil;
    private String  nom;
    private String  prenom;
    private String  login;
    private String  passwd;

    public Utilisateur() {
    }

    public Utilisateur(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Profil getProfil() {
        return profil;
    }

    public void setProfil(Profil profil) {
        this.profil = profil;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPasswd() {
        return passwd;
    }

    public void setPasswd(String passwd) {
        this.passwd = passwd;
    }
}
```

Am i missing somthing ? 
If you need more informations please let me know

Comment: It seems that ma.dao.impl.GenericDAO does not implement ma.dao.IGenericDAO

Comment: You're right, that was the problem. thanks for your quick answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your GenericDao not able to convert to IGenericDao and for that, there might be several reasons like is your GenericDao implements the IGenericDao, etc.

Also the following link might be useful if you are implementing GenericDao pattern:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251166/The-Generic-DAO-pattern-in-Java-with-Spring-and

Comment: Yeah you're right my genericDAO doesn't implement IGenericDAO , thanks it was very helpful